# Manually create json object from struct in golang

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a struct lets say

```golang
type Foo struct {
  A string `json:",omitemtpy"
}
```

And I know that I can convert it to json easily with something like

```
json.Marshal(Foo{})
```

and it will respond with an empty json string.

But I need to return a json representation of the struct with all fields and "empty values" present within the json using the same struct.  (in practice it is a very large struct so I can't just keep a copy without the tags)

What is the easiest way to do this?

Basically I need to create a json marshal of the struct that ignores the json omitempty tags.

This json creation does not need to be efficient or performant.

I would prefer if there is a library that exists for this type of task but most I have seen either create some special format or they respect omitempty

Edit:

Selected https://stackoverflow.com/a/77799949/2187510 as my answer with some additional work to allow for default values  (using their code as reference)

```
defaultFoo := FoodWithPts{ Str: "helloWorld"}
dupFooType := dupType(reflect.TypeOf(defaultFoo))
foo := reflect.Zero(dupFooType).Interface()

// New additions
defaults, _ := json.Marshal(defaultFoo)
json.Unmarshal(defaults, &foo)   // overwrites foo with defaults
// End New additions

data, err := json.Marshal(foo)
fmt.Println("dup FooWithPtrs:\n", string(data), err)
```

Output:

```
dup FooWithPtrs:
    {"String":"helloWorld","Int":0,"Bar":null} <nil>
```

Comment: You may need to create a copy of `encode.go` and delete [this line](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/encoding/json/encode.go;l=695), add some logic to set it to the empty value, and then call your version of marshal

Comment: I like this idea but am not a fan of copying standard built in libraries if I can help it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify tags at runtime, but you can create struct types at runtime using [`reflect.StructOf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StructOf).

So the idea is to duplicate the struct type, but in the duplicate exclude the `,omitempty` option from JSON tags.

You can find all below examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/hQAYlF0KLGD).

This is easier than one would think at first. We just have to do it recursively (a struct field may be another struct), and we definitely should handle pointers:

```
func dupType(t reflect.Type) reflect.Type {
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Pointer {
        return reflect.PointerTo(dupType(t.Elem()))
    }

    if t.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return t
    }

    var fields []reflect.StructField

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sf := t.Field(i)
        sf.Type = dupType(sf.Type)
        // Keep json tag but cut ,omitempty option if exists:
        if tag, _ := strings.CutSuffix(sf.Tag.Get("json"), ",omitempty"); tag == "" {
            sf.Tag = ""
        } else {
            sf.Tag = `json:"` + reflect.StructTag(tag) + `"`
        }
        fields = append(fields, sf)
    }

    return reflect.StructOf(fields)
}
```

Let's test it with this type:

```
type Foo struct {
    Str string `json:"String,omitempty"`
    Int int    `json:",omitempty"`
    Bar struct {
        Float  float64 `json:",omitempty"`
        PtrInt int     `json:",omitempty"`
        Baz    struct {
            X int `json:"XXXX,omitempty"`
        } `json:",omitempty"`
    } `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

First this is what the JSON output would be without type duplication:

```
data, err := json.Marshal(Foo{})
fmt.Println("Foo:\n", string(data), err)
```

Output:

```
Foo:
 {"Bar":{"Baz":{}}} <nil>
```

Note that we got `Bar` and `Baz` fields as those are structs.

Let's try with type duplication:

```
dupFooType := dupType(reflect.TypeOf(Foo{}))
foo := reflect.Zero(dupFooType).Interface()

data, err := json.Marshal(foo)
fmt.Println("dup Foo:\n", string(data), err)
```

This will output:

```
dup Foo:
 {"String":"","Int":0,"Bar":{"Float":0,"PtrInt":0,"Baz":{"XXXX":0}}} <nil>
```

Nice! Exactly what we want!

But we're not done yet. What if we have a type with struct pointer fields? Like this:

```
type FooWithPtrs struct {
    Str string `json:"String,omitempty"`
    Int int    `json:",omitempty"`
    Bar *struct {
        Float  float64 `json:",omitempty"`
        PtrInt int     `json:",omitempty"`
        Baz    *struct {
            X int `json:"XXXX,omitempty"`
        } `json:",omitempty"`
    } `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Attempting to JSON-marshal a value of the duplicated type:

```
dupFooType := dupType(reflect.TypeOf(FooWithPtrs{}))
foo := reflect.Zero(dupFooType).Interface()

data, err := json.Marshal(foo)
fmt.Println("dup FooWithPtrs:\n", string(data), err)
```

Output:

```
dup FooWithPtrs:
 {"String":"","Int":0,"Bar":null} <nil>
```

If the struct contains pointers, those appear in the JSON output as `null`, but we would want their fields too in the output. That requires initializing them to non-`nil` values so they generate output.

Luckily we can also do this using reflection:

```
func initPtrs(v reflect.Value) {
    if !v.CanAddr() {
        return
    }

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Pointer {
        v.Set(reflect.New(v.Type().Elem()))
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            initPtrs(v.Field(i))
        }
    }
}
```

We're excited! Let's see this in action:

```
dupFooType := dupType(reflect.TypeOf(FooWithPtrs{}))
fooVal := reflect.New(dupFooType)
initPtrs(fooVal.Elem())

data, err := json.Marshal(fooVal.Interface())
fmt.Println("dup and inited FooWithPtrs:\n", string(data), err)
```

Output:

```
dup and inited FooWithPtrs:
 {"String":"","Int":0,"Bar":{"Float":0,"PtrInt":0,"Baz":{"XXXX":0}}} <nil>
```

Nice! It contains all fields!

Comment: your shared playground does not work.      But this is exactly what I was needing!!

Comment: I have not done a ton with reflection but would this allow for values in the original struct to carry over? or would it be better to just do a `marshal original -> unmarshal (reflect instance) -> marsh (reflect instance)`


I can also just marshal both into `map[string]interface{}` and do a "merge" where keys overlap (on a most nested level)

Comment: @dtracers The playground link worked when I posted the answer. It looks like an internal issue of the playground, hopefully it'll past with time, try again later.

Comment: @dtracers Yes, it would work with JSON's limitation, question is how performant it needs to be. If performance doesn't matter, do what's simple and easy for you. If performance does matter, structs could support this "natively". Best would be to utilize struct embedding. If number of structs is not limited, a reflection-based solution could be crafted.

Comment: Yeah,  performance is not important here.

Basically creating a "all possible options" type response to optional settings which are stored in a struct. 

But everything needs to be "omitempty" otherwise these "options" would always override the "defaults" when unmarshling so this reflect option is really nice!